# Real numbers having disjoint neighborhood

Tags: general-topology

How does one prove that each point in real line has disjoint neighborhoods?

Comment: start by finding a point between any two

Comment: Do you mean to prove that the real line is [Hausdorff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space)?

Comment: oh. I was just mistaken.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Do you mean that any *two* points on the real line have disjoint neighborhoods? If so, consider that for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x\ne y$, the average $\frac12(x+y)$ is between $x$ and $y$. (Exactly halfway between them, in fact, though you don’t need that.)

If you really meant that there is a pairwise disjoint collection $\{V_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$ of open sets such that $x\in V_x$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$, that’s simply false: every pairwise disjoint family of non-empty open sets in $\Bbb R$ is countable, because each of them must contain a different rational number, and there are only countably many rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In any metric space, the set
$$
N_p(r)=\{x:d(x,p)<r\}
$$
is an open neighborhood of $p$. Given two points, $p\ne q$, we have $r=d(p,q)>0$.

Suppose that $s\in N_p(r/3)\cap N_q(r/3)$. The triangle inequality then says
$$
\begin{align}
r
&=d(p,q)\\
&\le d(p,s)+d(s,q)\\
&\lt r/3+r/3\\
&=\tfrac23r
\end{align}
$$
Contradiction. Thus, $N_p(r/3)$ and $N_q(r/3)$ are disjoint.

Answer (score -1):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, distinct points in $\mathbb{R}$ have disjoint neighbourhoods.

Comment: That doesn't really answer why it is Hausdorff.